# How do Group Appointments work at TLScontact centres for UK Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

My question concerns procedure for group document submission at TLScontact centres. We have booked and paid for 4 appointments at the centre in Kyiv. We were unable to get them consecutively, so two are at 10.30am and two are at 3.30pm. We want to use the 'group submission' extra service (a fee of 1500 UAH, about 50 GBP). It is not possible to book this service online, but it says we should pay in person on the day.

So, the question is, if all four family members turn up at 3.30pm and pay the group fee, will everything be processed normally, will there be any problems because the two 10.30am appointments were missed? On the TLScontact centre website the only extra information given is *All group members must have appointment on the day of submission*, which suggests to me that everyone coming for the 3.30pm appointment should be okay. Can anyone with experience of this confirm?

Comment: Did you end up receiving the visas?

Answer (score 1):

According to [TLScontact](https://uk.tlscontact.com/ua/kbp/page.php?pid=added_value_services), request for Group Appointment Service must be requested in advance by those who have been unable to book online, among other requirements. While you have two appointments on the same day, not showing up for one and appearing as a 'group' for another may not succeed.

> The ***Visa Application Centre will arrange Group Appointment Bookings*** for organisations, tour operators and large families who want to apply at the same time at the Visa Application Centre ***but they have been unable to coordinate appointments online***.
>
> This service also includes preliminary bundling of passports, saving time to the group leader when picking up ready applications.
>
> ***To arrange for the group appointment***, please speak to one of the staff members in the Visa Application Centre or contact us via the Feedback and Complaints section.
>
> Please note:
>
> - Only people traveling together are considered a group.
> - Group appointments ***have to be scheduled at least 1 working day in advance***, subject to availability.
> - All group members must have appointment on the day of submission. In case of having appointment for another date additional fees can apply.
> - This service does not guarantee that all applications will return on the same day as each application is treated separately.

***Added emphasis mine.***