# Family UK visa online application

Tags: visas, uk, applications, family

I have a family of 5 me my husband n 3children do we have to apply separately for each person online application n take the appointment date n time as wat option they give but how can whole family go seperate what is prime time charges they have no option of selecting their normal working outs it’s choosew the prime time n pay at the centre n no charges mentioned even then how to do wat to do plz help I will have to go how many times with all my children (family)

Comment: You must indeed apply separately and pay multiple application fees, but you ought to be able to combine your appointments.  If you cannot schedule consecutive appointments in the system, bring everyone to the first appointment and ask if they can take everyone at once (this suggestion comes from one of the linked duplicates of the suggested duplicate).

Comment: Many application centres do book group appointments, and you would do it online, as [this answer explains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104025/how-do-group-appointments-work-at-tlscontact-centres-for-uk-visitor-visa). If you show up as a group, you run the risk of having to return if the centre is unable to accommodate you on the day.